# how to show a image in a image view, chosen from an gridview.GridView is within in alert box

Tags: android

i am havin an activity which consist of a clickable imageview(with title "choose your image").Some thing like this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ImageView button = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.categories);
        button.setClickable(true);
```

now by clicking the image view a popup/alert opens consisting of a grid view form by images from my drawable folder.Something like this:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {   

        switch(id) {   

        case CATEGORY_ID:   

         AlertDialog.Builder builder;   
            Context mContext = this;   
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);   
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.categorydialog,(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));   
            GridView gridview = (GridView)layout.findViewById(R.id.gridview);   
            gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));   

            gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()   
            {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,int position, long id) {   
                 Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Position is "+position, 3000).show();
                 }   
            });

            ImageView close = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.close);
            close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v){
              dialog.dismiss();
            }
            });

            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);   
            builder.setView(layout);   
            dialog = builder.create();   
            break;   
        default:   
            dialog = null;   
        }   
        return dialog;   
    }
```

i am able to click these image.

Problem:
i want to choose one from these images and set it in the image view which user had clicked.
any suggestios!
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your `ImageView button` to a field

```
public class YourActivityName extends Activity
{
    private ImageView mImageView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.categories);
        mImageView.setClickable(true);
    }

}
```

Then in your gridview's onItemClick you can call
`mImageView.setImageBitmap` (or `setImageDrawable`.. whichever of the `setImage..()` methods you need).

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()   
{
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,int position, long id) {   
          Bitmap bmp = ...; //get your image at this position somehow
          mImageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }   
});
```

You'll need to get the image at the position which you clicked, but I will leave that to you since I don't know how your `ImageAdapter` works.

Comment: Also, this relies on you having the dialog and the mImageView in the same class.

Comment: doesnt have to be a field. could just find imageview by id.

Comment: I use fields for simplicity's sake but @Ian is right that you can simply do ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.categories)).setImageBitmap(bmp); when setting your image

Comment: Thanks for answer!Now i am in right direction.i have use your code in this way: Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
                  mImageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);

Comment: That will create an empty bitmap which will work fine. It will display nothing (since it's empty) when you set the value so it will appear to not work. I would check in the adapter if there's a getImage(position) method or something similar. If not, maybe try gridview.getAdapter().getItem(position); One of those could potentially get you the bitmap directly.  I can't really tell for sure without seeing the adapter code. Also, if this is the solution to your problem please mark it as such.

Comment: hey thank you very much!i was just puzzling last night with bitmap,bitmap factory stuff!i have done following changes as u suggested: Integer imageId = (Integer)((ImageAdapter)parent.getAdapter()).getItem(position);
                  Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),imageId.intValue());
                  mImageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);   and   public Object getItem(int position) {   
              return mThumbIds[position];   
         }